# How to hide vertical scrollbar and show horizontal scrollbar in table in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide vertical scrollbar and show horizontal scrollbar in talbe in HTML. If I use:

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; 
}
```

The result is both vertical and horizontal scrollbar are hidden. So, you can show me how to do with it ?

Comment: try `overflow-y:hidden`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow-y`

```
#element { 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me !!!

Comment: @KTu try adding you code, for example in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
#element{
   overflow-y: hidden;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **overflow**

```
#element {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
body{
width:100%; 
height:100%;
overflow-y:hidden, 
overflow-y:scroll,
margin:0 
}
```